# JQuery 1.3.2 with jsTree and draggables in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jstree

Question...I am using jsTree with JQuery 1.3.2, and have run into an issue when viewing my page in IE8.

I have added a jsTree control to my page, and have also used the Draggable behavior from jQueryUI 1.7.2 in an attempt to allow the user to drag a tree entry (leaf node) to another control.  I'm not using the draggable feature of jsTree.

This all works fine in Chrome and FF, but in IE I cannot select the tree node for dragging.  I can only grab the node if I carefully select "one pixel" (almost literally) to the right of my tree node text.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated to the latest version?

It was pretty much rewritten from scratch, and might have solved this bug (and others).